# Knockout not mapping correctly manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to read a JSON snippet into an oberservable array in knockout.js, but for some reason the properties of the contactGroup object never get set, can anyone shed any light on to why this happens? Thanks!

```
"contactGroups":[
    {"id":1,"name":"Test Group","contact":[{"name":"aaaaaa"},{"name":"bbbbbb"}]
}]

self.contactGroups = ko.observableArray([])

$(data.contactGroups).each(function(group){
    var temp = new ContactGroup({id: group.id, name: group.name})
    $(group.contact).each(function(contact){
        var temp_contact = new Contact(contact)
        temp.contact.push(temp_contact)
    });
    self.contactGroups.push(temp);
})

    function ContactGroup(data){
        var self = this;
        self.id = data.id;
        self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
        self.contact = ko.observableArray([]);

        function Contact(){
            this.name = ko.observable();
            this.email = ko.observable();
            this.telephone = ko.observable();
            this.mobile = ko.observable();
            this.mail_group = ko.observable();
            this.comment = ko.observable();
        }            

        self.addContact = function(){
            self.contact.push(new Contact);
        }

        self.removeContact = function(){
            self.contact.remove(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

observable arrays are functions so if you want to set an observable array, you should use `self.contactGroups(array);` instead of self.contactGroups.push(temp);

```
 self.map = function() { 
       var groupArr = [];
       ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.items(), function(item) {
          var temp_contact = new Contact(contact)
           temp.contact.push(temp_contact)
           groupArr.push(temp)
        });

     self.contactGroups (groupArr);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand this but it doesnt solve my problem. I am trying to create an array of Contact objects within each array of the ContactGroup objects

Comment: create a jsfiddle maybe ? what is the output you want.Its not clear.